Specification order by the last item of @OneToMany relation
I have Player entity, the entity has @OneToMany relation to PlayerTransfer, I want to order players by the latest transfer's budget.
Here's the summary of the entities:

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Player {
    
    // the other fields...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "playerTransfer")
    @Builder.Default
    private List<PlayerTransfer> playerTransferList = new ArrayList<>();

}


@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PlayerTransfer {

    // the other fields

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "player_id")
    private Player player;

    private OffsetDateTime transferTime;
    private Integer transferRate;
    private Integer budget;

}



Attempt-1
I have written a specification method like below, but it sends [ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression\] SQL error if player has more than 1 transfer.

public static Specification<Player> orderByBudget(boolean desc) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            Subquery<PlayerTransfer> sQuery = query.subquery(PlayerTransfer.class);
            Root<PlayerTransfer> subRoot = sQuery.from(PlayerTransfer.class);
            Subquery<PlayerTransfer> subquery= sQuery.select(subRoot).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(subRoot.get("player"), root));
            Join<Player, PlayerTransfer> playerTransferJoin = root.join("playerTransferList", JoinType.LEFT);

            Order order;
            if (desc) {
                order = criteriaBuilder.desc(criteriaBuilder.selectCase()
                        .when(criteriaBuilder.isNotNull(playerTransferJoin.get("budget")), criteriaBuilder.selectCase()
                                .when(criteriaBuilder.equal(playerTransferJoin, subquery), playerTransferJoin.get("budget"))));
            } else {
                order = criteriaBuilder.asc(criteriaBuilder.selectCase()
                        .when(criteriaBuilder.isNotNull(playerTransferJoin.get("budget")), criteriaBuilder.selectCase()
                                .when(criteriaBuilder.equal(playerTransferJoin, subquery), playerTransferJoin.get("budget"))));
            }

            List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>(query.getOrderList());
            orders.add(order);
            query.orderBy(orders);
            return query.getRestriction();
        };
    }


Attempt-2
public static Specification<Player> orderByBudget(boolean desc) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            Subquery<Long> subquery = query.subquery(Long.class);
            Root<PlayerTransfer> statusRoot = subquery.from(PlayerTransfer.class);
            subquery.select(criteriaBuilder.greatest(statusRoot.get("budget").as(Long.class))).where();
            subquery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(statusRoot.get("player"), root));

            Order order;
            if (desc) {
                order = criteriaBuilder.desc(subquery);
            } else {
                order = criteriaBuilder.asc(subquery);
            }
            List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>(query.getOrderList());
            orders.add(order);
            query.orderBy(orders);
            return query.getRestriction();
        };
    }

My another attempt is above, this method does not raise any exception, but it doesn't work that I want. Because subquery selects the max budget and order by it, I want to get the budget of the latest transfer.
Can someone help me out with the problem.
Summary, I want to order players by the budget of the latest transfer.
